# HOW TO FIX Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql

I am having the table called eventUserRelationMapping in that table there is two foreign key Event_id and Ringee_User_id. this eventUserRelationMapping doesn't have a separate DO class its under the UserDO class. here I am trying to get the EventUserRelationMapping for front end use. if I get the method I got the error like this

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ringeeapp_dev`.`event_user_relation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EVT_RINGEE_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RINGEE_USER_ID`) REFERENCES `ringee_user` (`RINGEE_USER_ID`))
```

but the data inserted in that eventUserRelationMApping table

this is my geteventUserMapping()method in DAOImpl

```
Override
    public List<UserDO> getEventUserRelationMapping(UserDO userDO)
            throws UserDataException {
        JdbcTemplate jd = this.getJdbctemplate();
        int isNotDeleted = IRingeeConstants.IS_NOT_DELETED;
      try
      {
          List<UserDO> userDOs = jd.query(GET_EVENT_USER_RELATION_MAPPING, new Object[]  {userDO.getRingeeUserId() , isNotDeleted }, new RowMapper<UserDO>() {
              @Override
                public UserDO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                  UserDO userDO = new UserDO();
                  userDO.setEventUserId(rs.getLong(1));
                  userDO.setEventId(rs.getLong(2));
                  userDO.setRingeeUserId(rs.getLong(3));
                  userDO.setAttending(rs.getInt(4));
                  userDO.setDeleted(rs.getInt(5));
                  return userDO;
              }
      });
            return userDOs;
    }catch (DataAccessException dExp) {
        throw new UserDataException("Error while getting eventUserRelationMapping for user " + userDO.getRingeeUserId(), dExp);
    }
}
```

this is query for GET_EVENT_USER_RELATION_MAPPING

```
private static final String GET_EVENT_USER_RELATION_MAPPING = "SELECT EVENT_USER_ID, EVENT_ID, RINGEE_USER_ID, IS_ATTENDING, IS_DELETE FROM EVENT_USER_RELATION WHERE RINGEE_USER_ID = ? AND IS_DELETE = ? ";
```

this is the test case of getEventUserRelationMapping

```
@Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void testgetEventUserRelationMapping() {
        ArrayList<UserDO> userDOs = new ArrayList<>();
        UserDO userDO = getUserDO();
        userDOs.add(userDO);
        UserDO userDO1 = getUserDO1();
        userDOs.add(userDO1);
        EventDO eventDO = getEventDO();
        eventDO.setRingeeUserId(userDO.getRingeeUserId());
        try {
            eventDAOImpl.addEvent(eventDO);
            userDAOImpl.addEventUserRelationMapping(userDOs,
                    eventDO.getEventId());
            List<UserDO> userDOs1 = userDAOImpl
                    .getEventUserRelationMapping(userDO);
            Assert.assertEquals(1, userDOs1);
        } catch (UserDataException uExp) {
            uExp.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();
        }

    }
```

please help me to fix this issue and why it happends

THIS IS THE MYSQL QUERY FOR EVENT TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `EVENT_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `RINGEE_USER_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `TEXT` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `PLACE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `EVENT_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `START_TIME` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `END_TIME` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IS_DELETE` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CREATED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `MODIFIED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`EVENT_ID`),
    INDEX `EVENT_ID` (`EVENT_ID`),
    INDEX `FK_EVENT_RINGEE_USER_ID` (`RINGEE_USER_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_EVENT_RINGEE_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RINGEE_USER_ID`) REFERENCES `ringee_user` (`RINGEE_USER_ID`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

THIS IS FOR EVENTUSERRELATION TABLE MYSQL QUERY

```
CREATE TABLE `event_user_relation` (
    `EVENT_USER_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `EVENT_ID` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `USER_RELATION_ID` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IS_ATTENDING` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CREATED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `MODIFIED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`EVENT_USER_ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `EVENIT_ID_USER_RELATION_ID` (`EVENT_ID`, `USER_RELATION_ID`),
    INDEX `FK_EVT_USR_USR_REL_ID` (`USER_RELATION_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_EVT_USR_USR_REL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_RELATION_ID`) REFERENCES `user_relation` (`USER_RELATION_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_EVT_USR_EVT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`EVENIT_ID`) REFERENCES `event` (`EVENT_ID`)
)
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of two tables?

Comment: u need query of the table?

Answer (score 0):

First i see an error in your @Test method

Assert.assertEquals(1, userDOs1); <==>  Assert.assertEquals(1, userDOs1.size());

To avoid this SQL Error you need to insert the data in your table and the in the join table 
Exemple : 
(tab1, tab2, tab_12)
Insert values into tab1 (commit)
Insert values into tab2 (commit)
Insert values into tab_12 (commit)

Comment: the values are already added in the table but still it shows error like this